# Getting both final price and out of stock products in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm working on some code for a Magento module and I've noticed a pretty major issue that I can't seem to find a clean solution for.

Basically, I want to fetch a collection of products as follows:

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->setStoreId($storeId) // $storeId is set earlier in the code
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFinalPrice()
    ->addStoreFilter()
    ->addUrlRewrite()
    ->getItems();
```

If I do this then in another place in my code where I'm iterating over this collection I can call `getMinimalPrice()` on individual bundle products and actually get the price of the product.

However, as long as I'm calling `addFinalPrice()` when fetching the collection all out of stock products are excluded from the collection. But, if I remove this call to `addFinalPrice()` then it's not possible to use `getMinimalPrice()` on bundle products (well, you can call it all you want but you won't get any data back.

So, I find myself in a problematic situation, how do I fetch a collection in a way that fetches **all** products, regardless of if they're in stock or not, while still fetching enough price data to actually get the price of my bundle products?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure it will solve your problem but there is function called **addPriceData** in the product collection model that helps to gather the information about the prices when you load the collection (instead of addFinalPrice). It can help to get the minimal price when the product is out of stock. For the final price, you can get it with the function **getFinalPrice** of **Mage_Catalog_Model_Product** or **Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price**. The second model has many interesting function for prices.

Comment: Unfortunately `getFinalPrice` gives me `0` as the price for bundle products and literally all `addFinalPrice` does is call `addPriceData`.